# How do I secure my pickle files correctly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, pickle, hmac

I'm following this [guide](https://pycharm-security.readthedocs.io/en/latest/checks/PIC100.html) to secure the pickle files correctly but I'm not getting the same output. Granted I had to do some changes to run it the first time:

```py
import hashlib
import hmac
import pickle


class Dummy:
    pass


obj = Dummy()
data = pickle.dumps(obj)
digest = hmac.new(b'unique-key-here', data, hashlib.blake2b).hexdigest()
with open('temp.txt', 'wb') as output:
    output.write(str(digest) + ' ' + data)

with open('temp.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()

digest, data = data.split(' ')
expected_digest = hmac.new(b'unique-key-here', data, hashlib.blake2b).hexdigest()

if not secrets.compare_digest(digest, expected_digest):
    print('Invalid signature')
    exit(1)

obj = pickle.loads(data)
```

When I run this I get the following stacktrace:

```sh
  File "test.py", line 21, in <module>
    expected_digest = hmac.new(b'unique-key-here', data, hashlib.blake2b).hexdigest()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/hmac.py", line 153, in new
    return HMAC(key, msg, digestmod)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/hmac.py", line 88, in __init__
    self.update(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/hmac.py", line 96, in update
    self.inner.update(msg)
TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is `data = f.read()`. `.read()` returns a string and `hmac.new()` wants `bytes`. Change the problem line to `data = f.read().encode('utf-8')` OR read the file in binary mode (`'b'` flag).

References:

- [7.2. Reading and Writing Files](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)
- [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)
- [`hmac.new()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hmac.html#hmac.new)
- [`.encode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=encode#str.encode)

Comment: This almost worked for me. I had to import the codec file and convert it that way instead for some odd reason instead of just using `.encode()`. It doesn't make sense to me

Answer (score 1):

I ended up having to use the following methods for it to work:

```py
pickle.loads(codecs.decode(pickle_data.encode(), 'base64'))
# and
codecs.encode(pickle.dumps(pickle_obj), "base64").decode()
```

Not sure why using `.encode()` and `.decode()` was still not working for me.